# rspec+capybara best practies to test cancan abilities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cancan

hy, i'm testing cancan with rspec+capybara.
whit an integration test I'm visiting all the pages that need to be protected with cancan.
I have many pages to test and for each page i have many abilities to test, so the comlessity is very high.
In your experience wich is the best practies to make a full test of the abilities?

Comment: Everytime i checked cancan abilities i usually used Cucumber for testing.  However you can create a user, assign him your role, and then simply check to see if he `can` do actions.  (thats what i've always done)

Comment: yes but i have many actions (becouse i have many controllers) and many abilities...So i have many cases to test. I'm looking for a simpler method

Answer (score 0):

Ryan Bates has a [wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Testing-Abilities) (scroll down to rspec) on how to test  abilities with rspec using be_able_to matcher

Comment: obviously i have just read this doc, I would like to know your opinion